# what is a Shock Absorber's Tightening Torque?

Tags: suspension, hyundai, torque, shock-absorber, wrench

What number should I adjust my Torque Wrench to when I torque a shock absorber?

the repair manual says 98.1 ~ 117.7N.m so should I adjust it to 98 or 117?

I have to change a leaking shock absorber on my hyundai 2015 Accent but I don't know how to adjust my Torque Wrench.

Comment: Go for the average about 110 would do...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Of course, you have had your torque wrench calibrated recently...

Comment: I've never seen torque listed as a range.  In the manuals I've seen, it's always a single exact figure.  Is this common and I'm just not aware of it?

Answer (score 2):

As Mike said in the comments, shoot for somewhere in between. Set your torque wrench and forget it. As long as you are hitting a number in between the specifications, your car and shock absorber will be just fine.